# What was the deal with Charles Widmore?

Tags: lost

Charles says to Ben that "Everything you have you've stolen from me".

We also learn that Ben somehow banned Charles from the Island.

It is implied (as I remember) that it may have been connected to when Charles sent Ben to kill Rousseau and Ben returned with Alex and they had an argument whether it was Charles or Jacob who wanted to kill the kid.

What exactly is the reason Charles got banned and was it him or the Island who wanted to kill the girl?

<sub>It is possibly 2 questions, but I think they are very closely related so possible it'll take just one answer.</sub>

Comment: Attempting to find logic in Lost. That way lies madness.

Answer (score 2):

Charles Widmore was originally one of The Others. When Ben was a kid back in the 1970s, he and Richard fell into odds about saving Ben's life when he was mortally wounded and The Others found him outside the Dharma compound.

Over time, his favor as the leader of The Others diminished as it was discovered he had been raising a child with Penney Widmore off-island.

Eventually Ben over-rides Charles leadership by turning the Others against him, stating he wasn't following "Jacob's will". During the purge of the Dharma folks, Charles is finally (under Ben's assumed leadership and demand) exiled from The Others when they assume control of the Dharma facilities. Hence why Widmore ended up on the mainland.

Hence why Ben "stole everything" from Charles.

source: I've seen the entire series five times through.

Comment: so what was the exact reason? which rule did he break? Was that just Penny? Ben couldn't just have him exiled because they struggled for power. And Alex, was that actually Widmore who wanted her dead initially?

Comment: If you get enough people under your thumb, believing what you want them to believe, you can accomplish whatever you want. Ben clearly had his "in" when Charles was discovered to have the child with Penney and use his influence as "following Jacob's will", to push the rest to follow him and turn on Charles. It happens all the time in real-life cultist groups. David Karesh slowly came in to the Branch Davidians, evetually became hyper-devout, proclaimed himself the new leader through "vision from God" and managed to turn enough of the group away from the original leadership.

Comment: (granted he was exiled at first, but managed to return with enough support). The point is... anyone, if they carefully play their cards right, say the right things, manipulate the right evidence, could infiltrate and take over a group like that. It happens in churches too. It's a classic power move.In regards to specifically, yes, he was also punished for leaving the island too often because of Penney. Leaving the island for the mainland's vices was not smiled upon. He also wanted Alex dead, as he saw a child and Rousseau as a threat to the Others' cause, he absolutely wanted them both killed.